# Method setHalfExpandedRatio(float ratio)

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

It's my first question in this incredible community.

I'm developing an android app in kotlin. I need a permanent bottomsheet (not modal). I have developed all the behavior that I needed, but for one detail.

I need to set de STATE_HALF_EXPANDED, by default is 50% of the screen, but I need 70%. I have visited this question:
[How i can set Half Expanded state for my BottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485481/how-i-can-set-half-expanded-state-for-my-bottomsheet)

In that question, the user Adauton Heringer explain how to do it in one of the answers. He said:

```
behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(your_bottom_sheet_xml)
behavior.isFitToContents = false
behavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.6f
```

I tried the same, because it looks like very easy to do. I did the two first lines, but when I try to used setHalfExpandedRatio() is like it wasn't exist. I have checked the official documentation and it is a public method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#sethalfexpandedratio

Am I doing something wrong?

My code is this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var bottomSheet: View = view.findViewById(R.id.departures_bottomsheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
        bottomSheetBehavior.isFitToContents = false

        // this doesn't work for me
        // bottomSheetBehavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.7 

        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(p0: View, dragPoint: Float) {
                val upper = 0.66
                val lower = 0.33
                if (dragPoint >= upper) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                }
                if (dragPoint < upper && dragPoint >= lower) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
                }
                if (dragPoint < lower) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                }
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(p0: View, p1: Int) {

            }
        } )
    }
```

I have this import:
`import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior`

And this implementation in build.gradle of the app:
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

In the layout file, the View is a child of a CoordinatorLayout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/globalMap"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/departures_bottomsheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
```

I have navigated to BottomSheetBehavior.class in Android Studio and this method doesn't exist.

Any help is welcome and I will be grateful.

If I don't find any other way, I will create a SubClass with this method.

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: Answer given by Nhât Giang fully solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [BottomSheetBehavior.java](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/5aebe1a1118029caefc7097749dd94aad4a084e0#diff-72fa9e19549d6b1e19f1100a6f90e008) commit history, the method `setHalfExpandedRatio(float ratio)` is added from version 1.1.0-alpha05.

You are using vevrsion 1.0.0, that why you cannot see this method.

**Solution:** Change version code from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0-alpha05 in your gradle file.

```
// implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

or using the latest version

```
// implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

You can find all available versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material).