# Xamarin BottomSheetBehavior halfExpandedRatio missing property

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to set BottomSheetBehavior in Xamarin.

This is how it is done, but not in Xamarin:

```
behavior.isFitToContents = false
behavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.6f
```

As can be seen by:

[Method setHalfExpandedRatio(float ratio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424273)

In Xamarin, there is FitToContents property, but there is no HalfExpandedRatio property. 
Is is missing?
Can I set halfExpandedRatio in Xamarin?

I need all 3 states: Collapsed, HalfExpanded (with ratio different than 0.5f) and Expaneded

Comment: Do you need to achieve it like following code? `var bottomSheetBehavior=  BottomSheetBehavior.From(xxxx);
  bottomSheetBehavior.FitToContents = false;
 bottomSheetBehavior.PeekHeight = BottomSheetBehavior.StateHalfExpanded;`

Comment: Yes, but I would like to set the halfExpandedRatio. PeekHeight is not HalfExpandedRatio. PeekHeight is size in pixels and it is used with StateCollapsed. HalfExpandedRatio is a float from 0.0f to 1.0f and it is used with StateHalfExpanded.

Comment: Xamarin Android have different with native android, You can try it `bottomSheetBehavior.PeekHeight = BottomSheetBehavior.StateHalfExpanded;` replace `setHalfExpandedRatio(float ratio)` in native android

Comment: Setting `bottomSheetBehavior.PeekHeight = BottomSheetBehavior.StateHalfExpanded` result is a very small bottom sheet in StateCollapsed, 6 pixels height, because that is the value of BottomSheetBehavior.StateHalfExpanded. Ratio is still 0.5f at HalfExpanededState.

Comment: I cannot find `setHalfExpandedRatio(float ratio)` this method in xamarin android.If ` mBottomSheetBehavior.State = BottomSheetBehavior.StateHalfExpanded;` cannot meet your requirement. You can set the `PeekHeight` dynamically depend on your needs. For example,  If you want to set  `behavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.6f`, we can set the value of `PeekHeight` to 0.6 times the height of `bottom_sheet`like following code.`mBottomSheetBehavior.PeekHeight = (int)(bottomSheet.Height*0.6);`

Comment: Which NuGet package are you using for this? Make sure you are using BottomSheet from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material/1.1.0-rc2

Comment: @Cheesebaron I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/28.0.0.3 I did download the one you suggested, but I cannot find BottomSheetBehavior class by now

Comment: It is in the namespace `Google.Android.Material.BottomSheet`. However, mixing support packages with AndroidX stuff will be a mess. The features you are looking for are simply not present in the support packages, you need to use the newer AndroidX/Material packages.